# Is the ROC Curve used only in the Binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, metrics

I'm starting to study Machine Learning now and I saw in some articles the ROC Curve being used only in binary classification.

Can I use the ROC Curve in MultiClass classification and measure my AUC ?

Answer (score 4):

ROC curves are typically used in binary classification also it can be used for MultiClass classification , but you have to binarize the output.
You can read here the example for multi class example:
visit https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: So if I want to compare the AUC of 3 different multiclass models, would I have to plot a ROC Curve with just 1 of the classes to make the comparison ? @Saitsh Saini